# XmlJavaTypeAdapter at package level not working

Tags: java, jaxb

I have the following in my `package-info.java`:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=OffsetDateTime.class, value=OffsetDateTimeAdapter.class)
})
package java.time;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;
```

and the following as an adapter:

```
package java.time;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class OffsetDateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, OffsetDateTime> {

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(OffsetDateTime v) throws Exception {
        return v.toString();
    }
}
```

But when I do the following:

```
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<Root> rootElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(node, Root.class);
```

I get the following:

> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory create0 INFO: No default constructor found on class java.time.OffsetDateTime

Do I have something missing from my setup - its not calling my adapter?

Comment: Have you tried to add an empty Constructor to the OffsetDateTime class?

Comment: @ReneM. - OffsetDateTime is a JDK class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html

Answer (score 1):

`java.time` is not the package where this should be. Annotations must refer to packages and classes in user space.

Place the package-info.java and OffsetDateTimeAdapter into the package where Root and its children are located.